# A book about time travel and a door with 4 keys

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to think of a book I read in middle school around 2010- 2012. it was about some kids who moved into a house and they found a door that had 4 keyholes in it, their parents didn't want them going into the door for some reason. I believe the three kids were siblings. they went through the door and found themselves time travel. The house was on a cliff I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Ulysses Moore: The Door To Time](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23300.The_Door_to_Time) by Pier Domenico Baccalario. 
The blurb seems a solid fit and several of the [reviews](http://garth.typepad.com/primitive_screwheads/2013/01/what-i-read-in-september-2012.html) mention that the secret door has four keyholes.

> *Eleven-year-old twins Jason and Julia have just moved from London to
>   an old mansion on the English coast. Their new home is filled with
>   twisting tunnels and strange artifacts from around the world, and the
>   twins can't wait to discover all its secrets. Before long, Jason,
>   Julia, and their friend Rick stumble upon a mysterious-looking door
>   hidden behind an old wardrobe. But none of the keys in the house will
>   open it. What lies behind the door? And why has someone tried to
>   conceal it? Jason, Julia, and Rick are determined to find out, no
>   matter what it takes....*

Comment: If this is the right answer, you'll be pleased to hear that it was an extensive series with at least 10 sequels; https://www.goodreads.com/series/52350-ulysses-moore